# \cventry ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end

Tags: errors, moderncv, line

I am having the same problem, when I first made this it worked ok, but now it shows the

```
late! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

in `\cventry{2014--2017}{Universidad San Antonio Abad del Cusco}{Escuela Profesional de Ingenieria Informatica y de Sistemas}{}{}{7mo Semestre}\newline{}%`, can someone tell me what is wrong please? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{Roy Richard}{Flores Gonzalez}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{img}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Datos Personales}
\cvitem{DNI}{46418393}
\cvitem{Fecha de nacimiento}{06 de Junio de 1990}
\cvitem{Lugar de nacimiento}{Cusco - Cusco - Peru}
\cvitem{Estado civil}{Soltero}
\cvitem{Dirección}{Av. Manco capac 718 - Wanchaq}
\cvitem{Telefono}{+51 948061939}
\cvitem{E-mail}{141004@unsaac.edu.pe}
\section{Educación}
\subsection{Educacion Superior}
\cventry{2014--2017}{Universidad San Antonio Abad del Cusco}{Escuela Profesional de Ingenieria Informatica y de Sistemas}{}{}{7mo Semestre}\newline{}%
\cventry{2007--2009}{Blue Ribbon International}{}{}{}{Chef Ejecutivo}\newline{}%
\subsection{Educacion Secundaria}
\cventry{2002--2006}{C.E.P Pukllasunchis}{}{}{}{}\newline{}%
\subsection{Educacion Primaria}
\cventry{1996--2001}{C.E.P Pukllasunchis}{}{}{}{}\newline{}%
\subsection{Idiomas}
\cventry{2006--2008}{CETPRO Maximo Nivel}{Ingles Fluido}{}{}{}\newline{}%
\subsection{Iasdddddddddddiomas}
\cventry{2006--2008}{CETPRO Maximo Nivel}{Ingles Fluido}{}{}{}\newline{}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newline` works inside arguments of \cventry `{ }` not outside, something like `{\newline Escuela Profesional de Ingenieria Informatica y de Sistemas}`

Comment: you were right i removed all the \newline{} i don't exactly remember why i added that in the first place, well THANK YOU all for your help, also, before i did that, i reinstalled miktex, i was getting a "log file not found", any idea why?

Comment: reinstallation was succesful, i was not getting any more errors, do you have any idea why the log file was missing? anyways thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to get rid of the error messages you should delete the `\newline{}` commands at the end of your `cventry` commands.

Perhaps you want to add more space between the `cventry` and the next section?  I would not recommend that but writing `\newline{}` into the first parameter to `\subsection` (see marking `<=====` in MWE) could be a very dirty hack ...

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Roy Richard}{Flores Gonzalez}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Datos Personales}
\cvitem{DNI}{46418393}
\cvitem{Fecha de nacimiento}{06 de Junio de 1990}
\cvitem{Lugar de nacimiento}{Cusco - Cusco - Peru}
\cvitem{Estado civil}{Soltero}
\cvitem{Dirección}{Av. Manco capac 718 - Wanchaq}
\cvitem{Telefono}{+51 948061939}
\cvitem{E-mail}{141004@unsaac.edu.pe}
\section{Educación}
\subsection{Educacion Superior}
\cventry{2014--2017}{Universidad San Antonio Abad del Cusco}{Escuela Profesional de Ingenieria Informatica y de Sistemas}{}{}{7mo Semestre}
\cventry{2007--2009}{Blue Ribbon International}{}{}{}{Chef Ejecutivo}%\newline{}%
\subsection{\newline{}Educacion Secundaria} % <=====================================
\cventry{2002--2006}{C.E.P Pukllasunchis}{}{}{}{}
\subsection{Educacion Primaria}
\cventry{1996--2001}{C.E.P Pukllasunchis}{}{}{}{}
\subsection{Idiomas}
\cventry{2006--2008}{CETPRO Maximo Nivel}{Ingles Fluido}{}{}{}
\subsection{Iasdddddddddddiomas}
\cventry{2006--2008}{CETPRO Maximo Nivel}{Ingles Fluido}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]